# Why is it that the string length of an empty array differs from the array size?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, sizeof, c-strings, strlen

When returning the length and the size of an empty string in C, the values differ. Why is that so?

```c
char b[7];

printf("String Length: %d", strlen(b)); // Returns 22
printf("String Size: %d", sizeof(b));   // Returns 7
```

Comment: Because if the array does not have the static storage duration then the code snippet behavior is undefined because the array is not initialized.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* because the array is not initialized? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your `printf` format doesn't contain conversion specifiers, so `22` nor `7` won't be printed.

Comment: The new code also invokes *undefined behavior* for type mismatch: `strlen` and `sizeof` returns `size_t` while `%d` requires `int`.

Comment: The array is not "empty", it is unitialised.

Comment: This question should motivate more why both functions are expected to return the same value here?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that the allocated space of your array isn't cleared.
So on the stack where you `char b[7];` is placed there is random data.
The strlen() function starts on you the memory location b[0] to search for an end character '\0'.

In your case the first '\0' character is found and the 23rd location resulting in a length of 22. This number of 22 is undefined behaviour and can be different everytime you run your code.

If you initialize your array with '\0' at b[0] it will return a length of 0.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `strlen` and `sizeof` gives different results is that the `sizeof` operator gives you the size of the array itself (in bytes) while the `strlen` function counts the number of "characters" until it finds a string null-terminator.

Even if you initialized the array (like e.g. `char b[7] = "a";`) the `strlen` function would give a different result from the `sizeof` operator.

There's simply no way you can make both give the same result without having undefined behavior one way or another.

---

Now as for why `strlen` returns `22` in your case, it's because uninitialized local variables, even arrays, really *are* uninitialized. Their values and contents are *indeterminate* and could be seen as random or garbage. Your array just happen to not have a random null-terminator inside it.

When you pass a pointer to the first element of the array to the `strlen` function, it will continue to look for the null-terminator even if it goes out of bounds. And in your specific case there just happens to be a byte corresponding to the null-terminator after `strlen` have counted 22 "random" or "garbage" characters.

Answer (score 0):

> When returning the length and the size of an empty string in C, the
>   values differ. Why is that so?

If the array does not have the static storage duration then it does not contain a string even empty. It is just uninitialized and has indeterminate value. So using the function `strlen` results in undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that these calls

```
printf("String Length: %d", strlen(b));
printf("String Size: %d", sizeof(b));
```

have undefined behavior because there are used incorrect conversion specifiers. You have to use `%zu` instead of `%d`.

You could declare the array like

```
char b[7] = "";
```

or like

```
char b[7] = { '\0' };
```

or even like

```
char b[7] = { [6] = '\0' };
```

In these cases the array indeed contains an empty string and the function `strlen` will return 0.

In any case the function `strlen` and the operator `sizeof` return different values because the function `strlen` does not count the terminating zero of a string stored in an array.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";

    printf( "strlen( s ) = %zu\n", strlen( s ) );
    printf( "sizeof( s ) = %zu\n", sizeof( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
strlen( s ) = 5
sizeof( s ) = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

One [fixed-size] array can hold different length strings (at different times, of course)

```
char t[10]; x = sizeof t; /* 10 */
x = strlen(t); /* BANG: t  is not valid */
t[0] = '\0'; x = strlen(t); /* 0 */
strcpy(t, "1"); x = strlen(t); /* 1 */
strcpy(t, "12345678"); x = strlen(t); /* 8 */
strcpy(t, "123456789"); x = strlen(t); /* 9 */
strcpy(t, "1234567890"); /* BANG */
```